DHCP and DNS issue
I have a domain controller (Windows 2019) with a DNS server. DHCP server is on a second Windows 2019 server.
Suddenly, the DHCP server stopped giving out new leases, so the clients get an IP address in 169.254 range.
On the DHCP server, I saw this message:
31,12/27/24,22:36:36,DNS Update Failed,5.6.6.100,VM03-W10-22H2.demo.local,,,0,6,,,,,,,,,9017

I did some digging. Some people advised to do a
dcdiag /test:dns /v > c:\dcdiag_dns.log && dcdiag /test:systemlog /v > c:\dcdiag_log.log

The results:
dcdiag_dns.log:
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

   Trying to find home server...

   * Verifying that the local machine DEMO-DC, is a Directory Server. 
   Home Server = DEMO-DC

   * Connecting to directory service on server DEMO-DC.

   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Collecting AD specific global data 
   * Collecting site info.

   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectCategory=ntDSSiteSettings),.......
   The previous call succeeded 
   Iterating through the sites 
   Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local
   Getting ISTG and options for the site
   Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=DemoOmgeving,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local
   Getting ISTG and options for the site
   * Identifying all servers.

   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectClass=ntDSDsa),.......
   The previous call succeeded....
   The previous call succeeded
   Iterating through the list of servers 
   Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DEMO-DC,CN=Servers,CN=DemoOmgeving,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local 
   objectGuid obtained
   InvocationID obtained
   dnsHostname obtained
   site info obtained
   All the info for the server collected
   * Identifying all NC cross-refs.

   * Found 1 DC(s). Testing 1 of them.

   Done gathering initial info.


Doing initial required tests

   
   Testing server: DemoOmgeving\DEMO-DC

      Starting test: Connectivity

         * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
         Determining IP4 connectivity 
         * Active Directory RPC Services Check
         ......................... DEMO-DC passed test Connectivity



Doing primary tests

   
   Testing server: DemoOmgeving\DEMO-DC

      Test omitted by user request: Advertising

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSecurityError

      Test omitted by user request: CutoffServers

      Test omitted by user request: FrsEvent

      Test omitted by user request: DFSREvent

      Test omitted by user request: SysVolCheck

      Test omitted by user request: KccEvent

      Test omitted by user request: KnowsOfRoleHolders

      Test omitted by user request: MachineAccount

      Test omitted by user request: NCSecDesc

      Test omitted by user request: NetLogons

      Test omitted by user request: ObjectsReplicated

      Test omitted by user request: OutboundSecureChannels

      Test omitted by user request: Replications

      Test omitted by user request: RidManager

      Test omitted by user request: Services

      Test omitted by user request: SystemLog

      Test omitted by user request: Topology

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyEnterpriseReferences

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyReferences

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyReplicas

   
      Starting test: DNS

         

         DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...

         See DNS test in enterprise tests section for results
         ......................... DEMO-DC passed test DNS

   
   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : Schema

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : Configuration

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : demo

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running enterprise tests on : demo.local

      Starting test: DNS

         Test results for domain controllers:

            
            DC: DEMO-DC.demo.local

            Domain: demo.local

            

                  
               TEST: Authentication (Auth)
                  Authentication test: Successfully completed
                  
               TEST: Basic (Basc)
                  The OS

                  Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard (Service Pack level: 0.0)

                  is supported.

                  NETLOGON service is running

                  kdc service is running

                  DNSCACHE service is running

                  DNS service is running

                  DC is a DNS server

                  Network adapters information:

                  Adapter [00000012] Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter:

                     MAC address is 00:15:5D:34:01:02
                     IP Address is static 
                     IP address: 5.6.6.1, fe80::cd4d:45fd:b68a:1b00
                     DNS servers:

                        5.6.6.1 (demo-dc.demo.local.) [Valid]
                  Adapter [00000013] Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter:

                     MAC address is 00:15:5D:34:01:03
                     Warning IP address is dynamic (can be a misconfiguration)
                     Warning: Adapter 00:15:5D:34:01:03 has dynamic IP address

                     (can be a misconfiguration)

                     IP address: 192.168.2.131, fe80::8b0a:b20a:1b69:719b
                     DNS servers:

                        Warning:
                        192.168.2.254 (<name unavailable>) [Invalid]
                        Warning: adapter

                        [00000013] Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter has

                        invalid DNS server: 192.168.2.254 (<name unavailable>)

                  Warning: The A record for this DC was not found
                  [Error details: 9003 (Type: Win32 - Description: DNS name does not exist.) - demo.local]
                  No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC

                  The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was not found
                  The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
                  Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found
                  
               TEST: Forwarders/Root hints (Forw)
                  Recursion is enabled
                  Forwarders Information: 
                     8.8.8.8 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                  
               TEST: Delegations (Del)
                  Delegation information for the zone: demo.local.
                     Delegated domain name: _msdcs.demo.local.
                        DNS server: demo-dc.demo.local. IP:5.6.6.1 [Valid]
                  
               TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
                  Test record dcdiag-test-record added successfully in zone demo.local
                  Test record dcdiag-test-record deleted successfully in zone demo.local
                  
               TEST: Records registration (RReg)
                  Network Adapter [00000012] Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter:

                     Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     b638d886-b8df-4527-9980-1d023d5e32a0._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching A record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     DEMO-DC.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.e5aa1c24-617e-4e4c-9017-70da72943a2f.domains._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kerberos._tcp.dc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kerberos._tcp.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kerberos._udp.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kpasswd._tcp.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kerberos._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.dc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.dc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _kerberos._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching A record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     gc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _gc._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.DemoOmgeving._sites.gc._msdcs.demo.local

                     Matching  SRV record found at DNS server 5.6.6.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.demo.local

         
         Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain

         controllers:

         

            DNS server: 192.168.2.254 (<name unavailable>)

               1 test failure on this DNS server

               Name resolution is not functional. _ldap._tcp.demo.local. failed on the DNS server 192.168.2.254
               [Error details: 9003 (Type: Win32 - Description: DNS name does not exist.)]
               
            DNS server: 5.6.6.1 (demo-dc.demo.local.)

               All tests passed on this DNS server

               Name resolution is functional._ldap._tcp SRV record for the forest root domain is registered 
               DNS delegation for the domain  _msdcs.demo.local. is operational on IP 5.6.6.1

               
            DNS server: 8.8.8.8 (<name unavailable>)

               All tests passed on this DNS server

               
         Summary of DNS test results:

         
                                            Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
            _________________________________________________________________
            Domain: demo.local

               DEMO-DC                      PASS FAIL PASS PASS PASS PASS n/a  
         
         ......................... demo.local failed test DNS

      Test omitted by user request: LocatorCheck

      Test omitted by user request: Intersite

and
dcdiag_log.log
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

   Trying to find home server...

   * Verifying that the local machine DEMO-DC, is a Directory Server. 
   Home Server = DEMO-DC

   * Connecting to directory service on server DEMO-DC.

   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Collecting AD specific global data 
   * Collecting site info.

   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectCategory=ntDSSiteSettings),.......
   The previous call succeeded 
   Iterating through the sites 
   Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local
   Getting ISTG and options for the site
   Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=DemoOmgeving,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local
   Getting ISTG and options for the site
   * Identifying all servers.

   Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectClass=ntDSDsa),.......
   The previous call succeeded....
   The previous call succeeded
   Iterating through the list of servers 
   Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DEMO-DC,CN=Servers,CN=DemoOmgeving,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local 
   objectGuid obtained
   InvocationID obtained
   dnsHostname obtained
   site info obtained
   All the info for the server collected
   * Identifying all NC cross-refs.

   * Found 1 DC(s). Testing 1 of them.

   Done gathering initial info.


Doing initial required tests

   
   Testing server: DemoOmgeving\DEMO-DC

      Starting test: Connectivity

         * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
         Determining IP4 connectivity 
         * Active Directory RPC Services Check
         ......................... DEMO-DC passed test Connectivity



Doing primary tests

   
   Testing server: DemoOmgeving\DEMO-DC

      Test omitted by user request: Advertising

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSecurityError

      Test omitted by user request: CutoffServers

      Test omitted by user request: FrsEvent

      Test omitted by user request: DFSREvent

      Test omitted by user request: SysVolCheck

      Test omitted by user request: KccEvent

      Test omitted by user request: KnowsOfRoleHolders

      Test omitted by user request: MachineAccount

      Test omitted by user request: NCSecDesc

      Test omitted by user request: NetLogons

      Test omitted by user request: ObjectsReplicated

      Test omitted by user request: OutboundSecureChannels

      Test omitted by user request: Replications

      Test omitted by user request: RidManager

      Test omitted by user request: Services

      Starting test: SystemLog

         * The System Event log test
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000416

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:01:15

            Event String:

            The DHCP/BINL service on the local machine, belonging to the Windows Administrative domain demo.local, has determined that it is not authorized to start.  It has stopped servicing clients.  The following are some possible reasons for this: 

                This machine is part of a directory service enterprise and is not authorized in the same domain.  (See help on the DHCP Service Management Tool for additional information). 

            

                This machine cannot reach its directory service enterprise and it has encountered another DHCP service on the network belonging to a directory service enterprise on which the local machine is not authorized. 

            

                Some unexpected network error occurred.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:39:50

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 192.168.2.254 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     16dc (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:40:11

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 8.8.8.8 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     16dc (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:43:26

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 192.168.2.254 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     1450 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:43:47

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 8.8.8.8 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     1450 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:44:33

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 192.168.2.254 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     1434 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:44:54

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 8.8.8.8 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     1434 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:46:29

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 192.168.2.254 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID      914 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:46:50

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 8.8.8.8 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID      914 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000272C

            Time Generated: 12/31/2024   13:49:41

            Event String:

            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 192.168.2.254 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID     17f0 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe), while activating CLSID {8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}.

         ......................... DEMO-DC failed test SystemLog

      Test omitted by user request: Topology

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyEnterpriseReferences

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyReferences

      Test omitted by user request: VerifyReplicas

   
      Test omitted by user request: DNS

      Test omitted by user request: DNS

   
   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : Schema

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : Configuration

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running partition tests on : demo

      Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom

      Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

   
   Running enterprise tests on : demo.local

      Test omitted by user request: DNS

      Test omitted by user request: DNS

      Test omitted by user request: LocatorCheck

      Test omitted by user request: Intersite

The binding:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-DhcpServerv4Binding -ComputerName demo-sccm

InterfaceAlias                           IPAddress            BindingState
--------------                           ---------            ------------
Ethernet 3                               5.6.6.2              True

The scope options:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-DhcpServerv4OptionValue -ComputerName demo-sccm

OptionId   Name            Type       Value                VendorClass     UserClass       PolicyName
--------   ----            ----       -----                -----------     ---------       ----------
3          Router          IPv4Add... {5.6.6.250}
5          Name Servers    IPv4Add... {5.6.6.1}
6          DNS Servers     IPv4Add... {5.6.6.1}
15         DNS Domain Name String     {demo.local}
67         Bootfile Name   String     {SMSBoot\x64\wdsm...
60         PXEClient       String     {PXEClient}
66         Boot Server ... String     {demo-sccm}
81                         DWord      {5}

And the DHCP -> DNS properties:

The DC has two nics: one for the internal network (5.6.6.x / 16) and one external network (for internet and remote access via RDP). It is running on HyperV. So, the IP address of 192.168.2.254 is from the external nic.
Last thing: nslookup works fine:
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup www.google.com 5.6.6.1
Server:  dynamic-005-006-006-001.5.6.pool.telefonica.de
Address:  5.6.6.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:400e:80d::2004
          142.251.36.4

What can I do to get my DHCP / DNS working again?
Feedback is appreciated.
With kind regards,
TheStingPilot
